# programmatically Overlay/add buttons on mjpeg view

Tags: android, button

I am developing my first android app for video door phone.
SIP Audio and mjpeg video functionalty are working
i'd like to add three buttons on bottom of video ui but there is only one button which i added on 3rd.
Thanks in advance for any responses

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String URL = "http://172.16.1.58/mjpg/video.mjpg";
    //String URL ="http://172.16.20.20/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=1&resolution=320x240";

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    setContentView(mv);

    // (1) add accept button on video screen
    acceptBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    acceptBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.answer);
    acceptBtn.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
    addContentView(acceptBtn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    acceptBtn.setOnClickListener(onAccept);

    // (2) add End key on video screen
    endBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    endBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.end);
    endBtn.layout(0, 300, 0, 0);
    addContentView(endBtn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    endBtn.setOnClickListener(onEnd);


    // (3) add OpenDoor key on video screen 
    keyBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    keyBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.key);
    keyBtn.layout(0, 600, 0, 0);
    addContentView(keyBtn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    endBtn.setOnClickListener(onOpenDoor);


    new ConnectToImageServer().execute(URL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never add the buttons to your view, and you need to do something like

`mv.addView(keyBtn);` for each of them.

however adding the 3 buttons might not give you the layout you want, so what you could do is make an xml layout with all the buttons in it and add that to your view. Using something like this, or programatically

```
    XmlPullParser parser = res.getXml(R.layout.buttonsForVidUI);
    AttributeSet attributes = null;
    int state = 0;
    while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        try {
            state = parser.next();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
        if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (parser.getName().equals("LinearLayout")) {
               attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

That said, if I understood correctly, what might be happening is all the buttons are overlapping eachother so all you see is the last one. Is the layout of the button that shows what you expect? A way to check this would be to set the background to one of them to black `keyBtn.setBackgroundColor(#000000)` and have the rest transparent `endBtn.setBackgroundColor(#00000000)` the last two 0s are the alpha channel.  I was having trouble adding buttons to views before because the view that I was trying to add them to was ignoring some of the layout parameters. In this case I had to add them all in the xml for the layout, would this be an option?

Comment: thanks Cob50nm.. I figure it out my 3 buttons were overlapped and I solved this issue with creating xml file..